# Permanently allow Xamarin iOS app to accept incoming connection (Xamarin Test Cloud Agent)

Tags: macos, xamarin, firewall, ui-testing, xamarin-test-cloud

My question is closely related with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845502/how-do-i-get-the-mac-os-x-firewall-to-permanently-allow-my-ios-app), as I am creating a Xamarin App and want to automatically test the UI. I've followed the instruction from the official [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/adding-uitest/) but once I do the last step, where I add `Xamarin.Calabash.Start();` into my AppDelegate.cs, my Mac keeps on asking me, whether it allows incoming connections from the App.

[image: Firewall Query to accept my application]

I can manually acknowledge the firewall rule on each startup of the app and when starting the tests, since the application is redeployed over and over again. However - if I don't, weird things start happening: Sometimes it works (I'm not sure why, possibly if I started the app manually before), sometimes I get exceptions like

`SetUp : System.Exception : Unable to start CalabashHostStrategyProxy`

Is there any way to permanently enable my application (especially the [Test Cloud Agent](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/introduction-to-test-cloud/#Xamarin_Test_Cloud_Agent_on_iOS) part) to accept incoming connections? Or at least to get rid of this dialog somehow automatically?

Would this affect my test-execution, if I run my tests in the Xamarin Test Cloud?

Comment: Please share solution if you found

Comment: Sorry, but I haven't. I gave up on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the iOS simulator app to the mac's firewall worked for me.

Have a look at the instructions over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40067738/1135847

(I didn't have to add the app I was trying to run, just the iOS simulator app).